# Adobe LiveCycle Forms: How to get web service response

Tags: web-services, adobe, livecycle, livecycle-designer

I need to call a web-service by button click and recieve some data from it, back to my form field.

Acording to [this](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/11.0/DesignerHelp/WS107c29ade9134a2c-1f4d3e3c12a7df3f73e-8000.2.html) article, I configured a small example, which uses [this](http://bernera.zapto.org/astronomy/astronomy.asmx?WSDL) wsdl, it's **moonPhase** method.

But as a result, whenever I click "Moon Phase Btn" moonPhaseResult field does not change it's value.

So, what am i doing wrong?

PS: my form can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/maprklpbssgaxzw/astrotest.pdf?dl=0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the issue was in not configured usage rights. A form has to have [Database and web service connectivity right](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/11.0/ReaderExtHelp/WS1a95df6a070ac5e34716067a12f7d24df97-8000.2.html).